# tsc: use version from node_modules

Tags: typescript

I've got TypeScript installed globally and if I do `tsc -v`, it prints out `Version 2.0.3`. I also have TypeScript as a dependency of my project so the compiler is also available as `MyProject/node_modules/.bin/tsc` which is version `2.0.6`.

Is it possible to configure global `tsc` to use the local version if in a project which has `node_modules`? The global `tsc` would basically become just a launcher of the local `tsc`.

Comment: Why not add a command to `package.json` to invoke the local executable?

Comment: That's a possible solution if all the devs on the project run `npm run tsc` instead of `tsc`, yes. Is it possible though to achieve what the question asks?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, no. `tsc` will invoke the global executable. It knows nothing about *"if in a project which has `node_modules`"*.

Comment: Thanks. Can you convert it to an answer? I'd mark it as accepted.

Comment: It's not really a definitive answer, just AFAIK! *"is it possible to..."* is a difficult question to answer in the negative.

Answer (score 1):

I do it using grunt-exec, but the pattern could be done a variety of ways. This cwd's down to the lib dir and then executes the command there.

This is my grunt-exec task, although I am trying to do it with better-npm-run now.

"ts-dev": { cwd: 'node_modules/typescript/lib', cmd: "node tsc -p ../../../../../ -pretty"}

Here is how I did it in better-npm-run see the task dev-compile.

```
      "scripts": {
    "build:dist": "better-npm-run build:dist",
    "build:prod": "better-npm-run build:prod",
    "dev-start": "bnr dev:start",
    "dev-compile": "bnr dev:compile"
  },
  "betterScripts": {
    "dev:start": "node ./serve https://opm-int.nane.netapp.com 9000",
    "dev:compile": "node ./node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc -p ../../../../../ -pretty"
  },
```

Comment: But this doesn't actually allow you to just run `tsc`, presumably you have to run some other grunt command.

Comment: I show how I did it with better-npm-scripts. It is simply using node to execute the tsc.js passing the -p back up to the parent location of tsconfig.json.

Comment: So you can then just run `tsc` in that directory?

Comment: That is what the command is doing. It is executing the local tsc.js

Answer (score 1):

You could just run `./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc -v` to run the node version

Comment: @Iony I think you meant to write, "to get the node version that tsc is using" rather than "to run the node version"